# When you spit out water during wudu is there water still in your mouth?

Tags: practical-islam, sawm, ramadan

I was fasting and then I was taking wudu then I swallowed my saliva but Im confused if I broke my fast or not because I think I swallowed water but also saliva.

Comment: If you swallow it intentionally, you broke your fast. This was on accident and without any intention so you didn't breakyour fast.

Comment: Thank you inshallah Allah will help you.